# cat not numbering lines of version output

Tags: linux, bash

When I type `echo Hello$'\n'world | cat -n` I get the output as expected:

```
  1  Hello
  2  world
```

But if I want to number line of `g++ -v | cat -n` I get an unnumbered result.

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/lto-wrapper
OFFLOAD_TARGET_NAMES=nvptx-none:amdgcn-amdhsa:hsa
OFFLOAD_TARGET_DEFAULT=1
...
```

What's wrong with my command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output of `g++ -v` goes to the standard error, not standard output. Redirect stderr to stdout to process it in a pipeline:

```bash
g++ -v 2>&1 | cat -n
```

Comment: Found that _g++ -v |& cat -n_ also works :)

Comment: @amplifier: Yes, it's an abbreviation introduced in bash 4.

Comment: @amplifier `|&` is a Bash specific implementation of the POSIX-shell standard's `2>&1|`. Using non-standard Bash syntax is a common source of issues; especially in CI pipelines, `cron` jobs and system agnostic shell scripting in general.